# Rails Relation with Duplicate Column Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a typical set of models with a parent/child/grandchild/ggrand hierarchy.  I create the relation with:

```
 @summary = Function.joins(:benchmrks=>{:indicators=>:results})
            .select("functions.id , benchmrks.id , indicators.id , avg(results.score) ")
            .group("results.indicator_id")
```

I had trouble accessing columns in my result set so I did this:

```
 @summary.each do |s|
     s.attributes
 end
```

and I see two columns defined and they are both accessible:

```
{"id"=>1, "avg(results.score)"=>3.0}
```

if I change my .select() and manually rename the columns to:

```
 .select("functions.id as f_id, benchmrks.id as b_id, indicators.id as i_id , avg(results.score) as avg")
```

I see 4 columns and they are all accessible:

```
 {"f_id"=>1, "b_id"=>1, "i_id"=>1, "avg"=>3.0}
```

so the dot SQL syntax of column names (functions.id, benchmrks.id, and indicators_id) seem to get collapsed into a single id by rails.  This was unexpected behavior to me.

Should I have done this a different way?

Comment: What does ```puts @summary.to_sql``` report out of curiosity?  I assume this should print out some SQL so we know what query is being built.

Comment: you did this correctly - using sql alias. This is one of the weird parts of activerecord, anytime you do a `join` or `find_by_sql` you get back an object that was used to generate the query (i.e. `Function` in this case) - but really the object will have all attributes specified in the select statement which can be a combination of the joined database tables, ideally rails would return a generic `Record` object in these cases it would be much less confusing

Comment: @summary.to_sql produces the exact correct query that I expect:  SELECT functions.id, benchmrks.id, indicators.id, avg(results.score) FROM "functions" INNER JOIN "benchmrks" ON "benchmrks"."function_id" = "functions"."id" INNER JOIN "indicators" ON "indicators"."benchmrk_id" = "benchmrks"."id" INNER JOIN "results" ON "results"."indicator_id" = "indicators"."id" GROUP BY results.indicator_id

Comment: @simusid I've never seen the `:benchmrks=>{:indicators=>:results}` style argument to `joins`. Can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: @house9 Independent of what Rails may be doing, shouldn't the SQL the OP shared in the previous comment result in an error because the SELECT includes items not included in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I think I saw my first hint of this syntax here http://www.landlessness.net/2010/09/rails-3-complex-join-query.html.   I also agree that my query probably should have failed for the reason you state.  I'm using sqlite currently, and when I move to mysql I will have to fix this (I'm lazy)

Comment: @simusid Thanks for the response. Are you saying, though, that the query _succeeds_ with sqllite (i.e. no complaints)?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin correct, on sqlite3 the query succeeds and returns the data that I expect.

Comment: @simusid That's weird. I guess it just picks a random row in terms of what to show for the non-grouped-by columns.